# Procedure is consuming lot of time

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created this procedure.

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    age_compare_group varchar(100);
    state_compare varchar(100);
    gender_compare varchar(100);
    income_compare_groups varchar(100);
    goal varchar(100);
    valuestring varchar(100);
BEGIN    

  OPEN cur FOR
   'select distinct a.age_compare_group, s.state_compare ,  g.gender_compare, i.income_compare_groups,goal_types.goal,goal_types.valuestring
      from age_group a ,
           state s ,
           gender g ,
           income_Group i ,
           (select ''goal'' as GOAL, valuestring
              from appldata
             where dataname like ''GOAL_CAT%''
               and datavalue in (select idcategory
                                   from goal_categories
                                  where typeuser = ''ECU''
                                and id_entity = ''B001''))goal_types';

LOOP                            

      -- process each row one at a time
      FETCH cur into age_compare_group,state_compare, gender_compare,income_compare_groups,goal,valuestring;
      insert into temp_test values ( state_compare ,age_compare_group );

 END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

But it is taking lot of time to execute.

I just want to know What so happening and can we optimize it by anyway.

Comment: Your query does not do any joins. You are creating a cartesian product between state, gender, income and the nested select - no wonder it's running slow. And additionally: you don't need the cursor at all. But first start with getting your `select` right Also: start using explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the error-prone implicit joins - if you had done that from the start you wouldn't have created the cartesian product in the first place.

Comment: yes because that's i wanted.

Comment: You *want* a cartesian product between all those tables? Do you understand what that is? I highly doubt that you really want that. And if you do, then why do you eliminate all the duplicates that get created because of the cartesian product using the `distinct` clause?

Comment: Isn't this basically an infinite loop as you have no exit-condition like `EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND`

Answer (score 2):

"One row at a time" is always slower than "all rows at once", and using dynamic SQL unnecessarily is slower than using static SQL, so why not try:

```
begin
      insert into temp_test values ( state_compare ,age_compare_group )
      select distinct s.state_compare, a.age_compare_group
            from age_group a ,
                 state s ,
                 gender g ,
                 income_Group i ,
                 (select 'goal' as GOAL, valuestring
                    from appldata
                   where dataname like 'GOAL_CAT%'
                     and datavalue in (select idcategory
                                         from goal_categories
                                        where typeuser = 'ECU'
                                and id_entity = 'B001'))goal_types;
end;
```

Comment: As much as I agree, I doubt that this will improve the performance. The problem is the select statement which seems to be completely wrong.

Comment: I also assume the query is wrong, this simple one `select distinct s.state_compare, a.age_compare_group
            from age_group a ,
                 state s` should return the same output  as yours

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to insert the query result to another table?
If so try to do it as follows,

```
insert into temp_test select distinct s.state_compare, a.age_compare_group
  from age_group a ,
       state s ,
       gender g ,
       income_Group i ,
       (select 'goal' as GOAL, valuestring
          from appldata
         where dataname like 'GOAL_CAT%'
           and datavalue in (select idcategory
                               from goal_categories
                              where typeuser = 'ECU'
                            and id_entity = 'B001'))goal_types;
```